# Microtik Routerboard Showing Ports Disabled in Role Unable to Edit

Tags: networking, router

How do I enable these ports that are in italics and Role column shows diabled? I looked all over Bridge Ethernet IpV4 settings and nothing to change the role.  This is for my home network where I am trying to just enable all the ports into bridge(pass-thru) to allow the Network provider to assign IPs.
[image]

Comment: You plug something in…?

Comment: DirecTv is plugged into 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your ports are *inactive*. They are not *disabled*. A disabled port would have an `X` flag instead of `I`.

To make your ports active, the hardware port needs to be active, ie. have a device connected. In “Interfaces”, the port must have the `R` flag (running). You must verify this first.

The “role” refers to the (Rapid) Spanning Tree Protocol role, which is certainly also relevant but an inactive port can never be in any role but “disabled”.